# User controls (listview, gridview etc) or Use  custom made tables or lists

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm starting a project in ASP.net, but since I first started with asp.net mvc. It's a bit weird with all the user controls you can just drag on the page and bind it with a datasource.

Is it bad practice to simply make a public variable on the code behind file and loop through it with a for-each like in asp.net mvc with the razor engine and making a table that way?

Comment: if you wanted to do something like that I'd use a repeater.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be bad practice other than the amount of time it would take to do and maintain. `GridView`, `ListView`, `Repeater` or another templated control will probably be your best bet.